# Требование заполнения select только когда видима

Tags: jquery

Подскажите. Как сделать так, чтобы требовало заполнения inbound_from только когда видимо(активно).

У меня требует даже если inbound_from скрыто

```
 if ($('#inbound_from').val() == null) {
         $('.errorrep').append('<h3>Выберете поле От кого</h3>');
            $('.errorrep').css({'display':'block'});
            $('#draggable').animate({
                scrollTop:  0
            });
            return false;
          }
```

HTML

```
<select id="inbound_from" name="blockger2016.inbound_from" onchange="mzchange()" style="display: block;">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="">От кого</option>
<option value="1">ГРАЖДАНИНОМ (ЛИЧНО)</option>
<option value="2">Ф</option>
<option value="3">Т </option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($('#inbound_from').hasClass("active") && $('#inbound_from').val() == null) {
  // ...
}
```

или

```
if ($('#inbound_from').css("display") != "none" && $('#inbound_from').val() == null) {
  // ...
}
```

---

И, пожалуйста, - "Выберите ..."

---

```js
function hide() {
  $('#inbound_from').hide();
}

function show() {
  $('#inbound_from').show();
}

function check() {
  if ($('#inbound_from').css("display") != "none" && $('#inbound_from').val() == null) {
    console.log("Error: option is not selected.");
    return;
  }
  console.log("All is good.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="inbound_from" name="blockger2016.inbound_from" style="display: block;">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected="">От кого</option>
  <option value="1">ГРАЖДАНИНОМ (ЛИЧНО)</option>
  <option value="2">Ф</option>
  <option value="3">Т </option>
</select>

<button onclick="hide()">Hide</button>
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Comment: Не требует выбора, я добавил html в задании

Comment: @dmr Что "Не требует выбора"?

Comment: Когда "От кого" - то нужно чтобы требовалось выбора value, он его не требует

Comment: @dmr Да, действительно, `$(select).val()` при выбранном `option` с атрибутом `disabled` возвращает `null`, а не `""`.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @dmr Пожалуйста. Успехов! Здесь считается хорошим тоном отмечать ответы "галочкой" слева.

Comment: Галка, которая смотрит вверх? Я ее нажал. Я правильно понял?

Comment: @dmr Не совсем. Вы, вероятно, пытались нажать стрелку голосования за ответ. Вы сможете это делать, когда Ваша репутация достигнет 15. Я имел в виду значок "птичка" - чуть ниже.

Comment: Понял, у меня заработала эта строчка  if ($('#inbound_from').css("display") != "none" && $('#inbound_from').val() == null) {

Comment: @dmr Порядок. Спасибо. Вы можете сделать это и для других ответов, которые получили ранее, если среди них есть полезные.